# Explorer / browser for offline file system

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

I am looking for an application that browses an *offline* representation of a file system with a representation as close as possible to Windows Explorer (or another file browser). Ideally It should maintain key metadata, including sizes, dates, etc.

One option I have is to browse the *saved* output from the following programs:

- treesize professional (not free)
- windirstat (update: windirstat doesn't allow one to save output)

This would be used to browse occasionally connected storage (external drive, network share, etc).

A bonus (nice to have) would be some sort of duplicate checking which detects duplicate *directories* (not just files).

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no ready program for doing ALL that...

If you're programmer, maybe you try [LogicNP Shell MegaPack](http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm) ?
You can create Explorer-like programs with it easily, if you know any  programming language
such as VB, VB.NET, C++, C# (which can use ActiveX or .NET objects).
They've both ActiveX and .Net versions of their products.
Also there can be a compiled explorer-like sample.